# ROW_NUMBER() fails using DATEDIFF output as ordering

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Can anyone tell me why this throws an error?

```
WITH date_diffs AS 
(
   SELECT
       ctd_item_id,
       ctd_assigned_to,
       DATEDIFF(d, ctd_assigned_date, ctd_review_completed_date) AS DATE_DIFF,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ctd_item_id ORDER BY date_diff DESC) AS RN 
   FROM
       irt_item_tracking_detail_tbl
)
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    date_diffs 
WHERE
    date_diffs.rn = 1
```

Error is

> Invalid column name 'date_diff'

Can it not be created within the `SELECT` statement in the `WITH`?

Comment: you can't reference aliases created in the same logical processing level

Comment: martin is right, solution is to create an outer loop to have your row_number() added